# android - Resources.getDimensionPixelSize is not equal to View.getHeight

Tags: android, view, resources, height, size

Does anyone know why the height is different for the following method calls?

1. *Resources.getDimensionPixelSize* returns 23 (S4 Mini), 60 (S6 Edge)
2. *View.getHeight* returns 27 (S4 Mini), 68 (S6 Edge)

The height is specified in dimens.xml:

```
<dimen name="entry_height">15dp</dimen>
```

That is the Java code:

```
View entry = findViewById(R.id.entry);
int itemHeight1 = entry.getHeight();
int itemHeight2 = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.entry_height);
```

The entry.xml is a simple LinearLayout with a fix height:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/entry" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="@dimen/entry_height">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to state that using getDimensionPixelOffset instead of getDimensionPixelSize does not solve the issue.

Comment: I think your view has a 1dp padding, maybe from `styles.xml`? can you set padding to 0 and check it again?

Comment: What is the result of `entry.getMeasuredHeight()`?

Comment: The result of Measured height is equal to getDimensionPixelSize. Unfortunately <item name="android:padding">0dp</item> in styles.xml does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it. The problem is caused by my layout file. The height of the `LinearLayout` is ignored if there is any view inside the `LinearLayout` view that has a fix height attribute.